# global tool configurations in jenkins through cli?

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-cli

Is there a way to add global tool configurations for artifactory and aws in jenkins through cli?

I'm trying to write chef cookbook for automating creation of Jenkins job, but I don't know how to add credentials for tools.

Comment: try showing what you have accomplished so far and the error messages you are currently receiving

Comment: I'm taking the template of job from jenkins but tool configurations and credentials are not coming in that template

Answer (score 0):

Credentials don't depend on the tools which will use them.
You can register credentials in general through the [JENKINS Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) API: see for instance

- [How to create jenkins credentials via the REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29616660/6309) (similar to [jenkins_api_client issue 162](https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client/issues/162#issuecomment-228133421))
- [update Jenkins credentials by script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32208763/6309)

You can then use those credentials in association with a Jenkins Job.

Comment: I have to write a chef cookbook , so i need everything to be done from command line , Is it possible with this method?

Comment: Not needed with the chef cookbook, as this provides a wrapper for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is twofold.

### Credentials

The [Jenkins](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins) chef cookbook offers a [`jenkins_credentials`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins#jenkins_credentials) resource, which allows you to pipe credentials (using Jenkins API internally) into your Jenkins instance.

### Global Tool Configuration

You can use the [`jenkins_script`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins#jenkins_script) resource of the same cookbook to execute any Groovy script. This allows you to configure your Jenkins instance. You now just have to figure out exactly, what the code is to, e.g., select the previously defined credentials. But the code looks similarly to the example given in the cookbook's README.

Comment: Thank you.. I'm trying that.